# Ubuntu Customization Kit Error

Tags: uck

I am trying to use UCK but I got this error when I ran it:

I ran it from the source (svn repo), not the deb package.

```
Build (/home/joel/uck-2.4.5/uck-gui ) started at 2011-11-25 15:38:56
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Build ended at 2011-11-25 15:39:17
```

I chose "en" then Yes to all questions and I got this error. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the uck-2.4.5 which has problems, I am using the .deb version which works, simply use this command to install:

```
sudo apt-get install uck
```